# Why multiplier is disabled in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

[image]

I cannot understand why it's disabled? How can I change it's value?

Comment: Try double clicking on the constraint (rather than clicking the edit popup) and see if it is available there

Comment: I did it already. The same thing. I did not even found there multiplier field

Comment: why would you set the multiplier on a constant width?

Comment: @Wain I want to place 2 buttons by 50% near with each other

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most constraints have the following pattern:

```
attribute = referenceView.attribute * multiplier + constant
```

`Width` is a constraint that is applied only to one item. It doesn't have any reference view.

Since there is no `referenceView`, the expression is just

```
attribute = constant
```

That's why `multiplier` is disabled.

If you want the `width` to be the multiple of some other view's `width`, you should create a constraint `Equal widths` with another view and then change the multiplier.

[image: Interface builder]

Comment: I did not understand this line `between two views` =/